# iOS UIAlertView Other Button Action

Tags: cocoa-touch, uialertview

I have this code currently for my UIAlertView:

```
if (counter > highscore) { //if highscore is achieved show an alert
    highscore = counter;
    NSString *nssHighscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", highscore];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Congratulations, You Got A New High Score!!"
                              message:nssHighscore
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Share"];
    [alert show];
}
```

I want to run this code when the 'Share' button is clicked on the Alert

```
- (IBAction)PostToFacebook:(id)sender {
    NSString *nssHighscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", highscore];
    mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My New Highscore is %d - Try to Beat it!, highscore]];
    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

So far I've been following guides and questions on stack overflow but can't get it working.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to use the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method, and check that the index matches `[alertView firstOtherButtonIndex]`.

Like this:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Congratulations, You Got A New High Score!!"
                          message:nssHighscore
                          delegate:self // <== changed from nil to self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Share"];
```

And in the same class:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == [alertView firstOtherButtonIndex]) {
        [self PostToFacebook:self];
    }
}
```